# SFDX not grabbing Recommendations

Tags: salesforcedx

It seems that the SFDX Plugin or Visual Code does not support Recommendations. It does not grab them.

I made a full flow of a Next Best Action including Page Layout Changes, Flows, Recommendation**Strategies** and Recommendations. All Changes are synced except Recommendations.

An installed Package delivers all parts except the recommendation. Therefor I cannot deliver the next best action out of the box.

I already searched for a bug or limitation but did not find anything. Does anybody know about it?

Comment: When you say "the plugin", are you using `source:push/pull` or `source:retrieve/deploy`? I don't know recommendations yet, but according to the metadata coverage report, `RecommendationStrategy` is a [supported](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/46/RecommendationStrategy/details) object for MDAPI. Although not for a managed package yet.

Comment: @pchittum im using psuh/pull and you are right Strategies are part of the Sync but not the Recommendation itself. But thanks for your link! The missing part is "Recommendation" which is not mentioned on the link side. Gonna Ask Salesforce Support....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how you implement and put together recommendations, so bear that in mind.

Looking at a few things in the command line, it appears that while `RecommendationStrategy` is a metadata object, `Recommendation` itself is a *data* object.

If I try to inspect the schema using the Tooling API, it fails:

```
> sfdx force:schema:sobject:describe -u myorgalias -t -s Recommendation

ERROR running force:schema:sobject:describe:  The requested resource does not exist
```

On the other hand, if I take the `-t` off, I get the output that defines the object.

```
> sfdx force:schema:sobject:describe -u blixtar -s Recommendation
{ actionOverrides: [],
  activateable: false,
  childRelationships:
    [ { cascadeDelete: false,
        childSObject: 'FlowRecordRelation',
        deprecatedAndHidden: false,
        field: 'RelatedRecordId',
        junctionIdListNames: [],
        junctionReferenceTo: [],
        relationshipName: null,
        restrictedDelete: false } ],
  compactLayoutable: true,
  createable: true,
  custom: false,
  customSetting: false,
  deletable: true,
  ...
  label: 'Recommendation',
  labelPlural: 'Recommendations',
  ...
  name: 'Recommendation',
  namedLayoutInfos: [],
  networkScopeFieldName: null,
  queryable: true,
  recordTypeInfos:
    [ { ... } ],
  replicateable: true,
  retrieveable: true,
  searchLayoutable: true,
  searchable: true,
  supportedScopes: [ { label: 'All recommendations', name: 'everything' } ],
  triggerable: true,
  undeletable: false,
  updateable: true,
  urls: {...} }
```

This would suggest that there is no need to sync recommendations in the process of deploying changes. Again, I make that statement in ignorance of using the Recommendations features. But inferring a bit from past usage of inbound marketing tools that used recommendation engines, it would follow that the "recommendation" would be the tracking of the business transaction whereby a recommendation was proposed to a customer or agent, and then either accepted or rejected by the customer.

Digging into the fields a bit, it isn't obvious to me what the association field should be, and what you're to associate it to, but if there were a need to move this data between a build/test/prod environment, it could potentially be accomplished by using the the `force:data:record|bulk|tree` commands in combination with some scripting, and/or use of `jq` as you do your deployment. The schema describe indicates you have full data access tools to the object (createable, updateable, searchable, queryable, deletable all seem to be enabled).

That's where I'd start. If you need a more sophisticated/cleaner approach, and you have the time to invest, you could extend the Salesforce CLI with a custom plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Got following Information from Salesforce itself:
Salesforce Support  July 18 at 1:06 PM BST

*Assuming that it is correct, I've begun investigating the Org and our own records to determine if this is a case of missing documentation or just an unsupported Object. [...]
However, on creating on a base Salesforce Developer Org, which has Recommendations present in it as an object, I can find no corresponding metadata component. This means that the object has no relevant metadata component and cannot be extracted via CLI. As a workaround, I would suggest creating a package.xml component that contains the Recommendaiton object as well as the other objects;
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm*

*I understand this is frustrating, as it adds extra steps to your operations, but I am afraid it is likely the only way to get the changes made to Recommendation to be packaged with the other changes made.*